# Dropzone JS not able to upload file

Tags: javascript, php, image-uploading, dropzone.js

I'm using Dropzone JS and from my frontend (localhost:9000), I'm calling a upload.php where I get the images and then upload it on the backend (localhost:80)in a folder.
**here is my html :**

```
 <form action="localhost:80/ProgettoTimelinegit/api/upload.php" class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 </form>
```

**my javascript :**

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
$("#my-dropzone").options = { 
    maxFilesize: 4, // MB
    url:"http://localhost:80/ProgettoTimelinegit/api/upload.php",
    addRemoveLinks : true,
    uploadMultiple:true,
    paramName:"file",
    parallelUploads: 2,
    maxFiles: 10,
    autoProcessQueue: true,
    headers: {
        // remove Cache-Control and X-Requested-With
        // to be sent along with the request
        'Cache-Control': null,
        'X-Requested-With': null
    }
};
```

and upload.php

```
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  //1
$storeFolder = '/xampp/htdocs/images/';   //2

if(!empty($_FILES)) {
    // START // CREATE DESTINATION FOLDER
    define('DESTINATION_FOLDER','../api/upload/');

    if (!@file_exists(DESTINATION_FOLDER)) {
        if (!mkdir(DESTINATION_FOLDER, 0777, true)) {
            $errors[] = "Destination folder does not exist or no permissions to see it.";
        }

        // END // CREATE DESTINATION FOLDER
        $temp = $_FILES['file[]']['tmp_name'];
        $dir_seperator = "fold/";

        //$destination_path = dirname(__FILE__).$dir_seperator.$folder.$dir_seperator;
        $destination_path = DESTINATION_FOLDER.$dir_seperator;
        $target_path = $destination_path.(rand(10000, 99999)."_".$_FILES['file']['name']); 
        move_uploaded_file($temp, $target_path);
    }
}
```

If I upload the image, in console (for every browser)
it

```
POST localhost:80/ProgettoTimelinegit/api/upload.php net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

*What I want to do is to load the image in localhost:80/progettoTimelinegit/api/upload/*

Comment: I've used the tutorial from https://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/how-to-build-a-file-upload-form-using-dropzonejs-and-php

Answer (score 0):

Your `upload.php`-file is already in the `api`-folder, just change this line:

`define('DESTINATION_FOLDER','../api/upload/');`

to:

`define('DESTINATION_FOLDER','upload/');`

And it should work. You have quite a few weird variables, unused variables etc., so there might be other things wrong as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to make it work, it costed me 4 days of work but now it works :
you have to be careful in some part of your code :

**Html**

```
Do not add enctype="multipart/form-data" or if you do remember to add rewrite rule
```

*"multipart/form-data" make dropzone **AUTOMATICALLY** set Options REQUEST*

**virtual host or a .ini / .htAccess with Xampp/wampp/vagrant**

```
VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "#folderOfyourWebsite"
    ServerName yoursite.name
     <Directory "#path To The HTML of Your Index Page">
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
         AllowOverride Authconfig FileInfo
         Require all granted
        </Directory>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"      
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
        Header set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
  </VirtualHost>
```

*In rewrite engine we're telling him : ok,if you receive An options request, rewrite it with a 200 (successfull post)*

So your TO-DO list can be recapped with this :

1. check your html dropzone Form, if you have enctype you'll have to write
   a Rewrite Rule in your vhost or htaccess
2. Did you write a **Rewrite Rule** in order to make cors Successfull?
3. Make sure your path have all permissions and your upload folder exists
4. Check your static paths wherever you are doing an http request